# Getting information of user from oauth2 app having the session token

Tags: reactjs, authentication, go, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm having I think, a misunderstanding of concepts related with Oauth2 protocol. Right now I have 3 applications:

1. Frontend developed in React
2. OAuth2 server developed in Golang (not finished)
3. Another backend app, let's call it: Bussiness Logic app

At first, the user from react can login in the system using the OAuth2 server, the OAuth2 server sends the token and everything's perfect.
Now, when from the the react app some request is send to the Bussiness Logic App the token is also send in the headers. My question is: having the token, should I be able from the Bussiness Logic App to get information fo the user making a request to the OAuth server? is it allowed in the OAuth protocol?

The thing is that I need to know in the Bussiness Logic App which user is logged in, if it's not allowed, how should I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

No.

[OAuth 2.0 NOT an Authentication protocol.](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/OAuth%202.0%20NOT%20an%20Authentication%20protocol) 
If you need Identity Information you need to use OpenID Connect (which is built on OAuth 2.0)

With OpenID Connect you are provided both an Access Token and an Identity Token. The Identity Token will contain "basic" profile information about the "user". The Access Token may be used to obtain more detailed information about the user from the userinfo_endpoint.